# ion 2 calendar monthChange event not working

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, calendar, ionic6

I am using ion2-calendar version 3.5.0

without implementing the monthChange event it is working fine, but when I add like this:

```html
<ion-calendar [options]="cal_options" [(ngModel)]="selectedDates" (monthChange)="onMonthChanged($event)" (change)="onChange($event)">
</ion-calendar>
```

On month change function:

```javascript
 onMonthChanged(month) {
  this.selectedMonth = month.newMonth.months;
 }
```

When I switch month, it keeps displaying the current month

Images attached:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB2Wm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7gZq.png)

Comment: please post complete code. what is "onMonthChanged" ?

Comment: @E.Maggini Added onMonthChange Function in the question

Answer (score 0):

**This is how I got my selected month, I hope this will be helpful**

`onMonthChanged($event: any) {`
`const newMonthArr = $event.newMonth.string.split('-');`
`const [year, month, day] = newMonthArr;`
`console.log(month);`
}`